# Is it possible to migrate OS X Server user passwords to Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, mac-osx, ftp

I have an FTP server running on OS X Server 10.6 and I would like to migrate it to CentOS. Is it possible to migrate user passwords from OS X Server to Linux?

Comment: In general securely stored password (those stored with a strong salted hash, etc) can't be migrated any more than they can be easily cracked. In almost all cases of migrations such as these mass password resets are inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

No. MacOS server stores the passwords in it's own proprietary password database and there is no way that I know of to get the passwords out of it in any usable form.

Comment: Oh, they store it in a regular SHA-512 format. But anyways, that's not necessarily compatible to what Linux is using - md5 or sha-1, at it's best. Since I don't know if you can set the Linux-shadows to SHA-512 I didn't bother to answer this question. It's out of my expertise...